How to fix "Files" in a ubuntu 24.04 VM?
I just creates a fresh ubuntu 24.04 VM on a windows host and noticed that the "FILES" is not working. Here is a screenshot of my screen:

The output of ubuntu-drivers devices is:
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000015ADd00000405sv000015ADsd00000405bc03sc00i00
vendor   : VMware
model    : SVGA II Adapter
driver   : open-vm-tools-desktop - distro free


Did you install e.g.Guest additions for Virtualbox, there is a similar one for VMWare... I'd say these contain a "graphics driver" - for the VM:s simulated "hardware".

Yes, in the menu I selected "Devices" -> "Upgrade Guest Additions", let it install and rebooted. No change.

Sorry, with only one driver choice available, reinstalled and rebooted: Out of ideas.

One more idea: $ sudo apt --reinstall install nautilus - to reinstall "Files" (the same as Nautilus) - see if that helps. You MIGHT need to provide network access to Ubuntu though.

Try this:
$ ubuntu-drivers -h for some terse info,
Do $ ubuntu-drivers devices, then select one of the listed drivers, copy the text between : and - and append it to $ ubuntu-drivers install ... instead of ..., let it run, reboot... Try it out.
The same using GUI: Hit Windows key, begin type additional drivers and select the greenish iconn that appears... click on a driver version and it will start install... reboot.
note: you might need to go through several of them, to check which one actually works.

I added the output to my question above. I do not understand what you mean by the instructions in your answer ...

Well, i relaized just at the very end of writing this that you were using a VM. The above is more suitable for a real Linux, where you might have several versions of drivers. (e.g. With a nVidia GPU and the main Ubuntu 24.04 version, I see 8 versions, on top of the X.org driver)

I'll leave this for now. Will probably delete it after some time as it doesn't help you much.

The problem seem to have caused by the VirtualBox setting "3D acceleration"! If that option is enabled -> really serious UI issues.
Solution: Disable 3D Acceleration for VirtualBox
